# CheckBox CheckChanged event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, checkbox

After `Checkbox.IsChecked = true`, the Checked event is fired. 
After `Checkbox.IsChecked = false`, the UnChecked event is fired.
But what event is fired after `IsChecked = null`?

Comment: And just how would you fire that event?

Comment: I need an event after Checkbox.IsChecked = null. I don't understand why is there no IsCheckedChanged event like in WinForms the CheckedChanged event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The check box will show an **indeterminate** state when `IsChecked` is set to null. Look at this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) for more details. You can write code in indeterminate state like this:

```
<CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked"
 Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked"
 Indeterminate="CheckBox_Indeterminate"
 IsThreeState="True"/>
```

And in the code behind:

```
private void CheckBox_Indeterminate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //write some code in Indeterminate states
}
```

**Indeterminate** is an event that occurs when the state of a `CheckBox` is switched to the indeterminate state. You can check this link about [Indeterminate Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.indeterminate(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, **indeterminate** is the event where I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The event is called `Indeterminate`. It fires when you set the `IsChecked` property to null or nothing. [See this page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.indeterminate(v=vs.110).aspx)